# C remove special characters from string

Tags: c, string, replace, char, segmentation-fault

I am very new to C, and I have created a function that removes special characters from a string and returns a new string (without the special characters).

At first glance, this seemed to be working well, I now need to run this function on the lines of a (huge) text file (1 Million sentences). After a few thousand lines/sentences (About 4,000) I get a seg fault.

I don't have much experience with memory allocation and strings in C, I have tried to figure out what the problem with my code is, unfortunately without any luck. 
Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *preproccessString(char *str) {
    // Create a new string of the size of the input string, so this might be bigger than needed but should never be too small
    char *result = malloc(sizeof(str));
    // Array of allowed chars with a 0 on the end to know when the end of the array is reached, I don't know if there is a more elegant way to do this
    // Changed from array to string for sake of simplicity
    char *allowedCharsArray = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    // Initalize two integers
    // i will be increased for every char in the string
    int i = 0;
    // j will be increased every time a new char is added to the result
    int j = 0;
    // Loop over the input string
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        // l will be increased for every char in the allowed chars array
        int l = 0;
        // Loop over the chars in the allowed chars array
        while (allowedCharsArray[l] != '\0') {
            // If the char (From the input string) currently under consideration (index i) is present in the allowed chars array
            if (allowedCharsArray[l] == toupper(str[i])) {
                // Set char at index j of result string to uppercase version of char currently under consideration
                result[j] = toupper(str[i]);
                j++;
            }
            l++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is the rest of the program, I think the problem is probably here.

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char const * const fileName = argv[1];
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char line[256];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        printf("%s\n", preproccessString(line)); 
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```char *result``` should be malloced to the length of the str + 1 ```char *result = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);```

Comment: @MichaelBianconi This doesn't solve the problem, it still gives me a seg fault at the same position.

Comment: Why not do it with a pre-written tool like `tr`?

Comment: Can you humor me and add a ```break;``` after ```result[j] = toupper(str[i])); j++;```?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi This works. (Only for the first char, but I don't get a seg fault)

Comment: You're not adding a null terminator to the `result` string. Put `result[i] = 0;` before `return result;`

Comment: @b3nj4m1n Did you add it within the same indented block? (Before the ```}```)

Comment: @Barmar Still a seg fault at the same position.

Comment: You may have other problems in the rest of your program.

Comment: @Barmar I can read the file without any problems (And print out the full lines, just with the special chars), and there is nothing else in the programm.

Comment: @b3nj4m1n Can you add the code that calls `preprocessString` so we can see the call to `free` and make sure that's correct?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I added the rest to the programm, I'm not sure if i free it....

Comment: @b3nj4m1n: No you don't, and that is the problem. Store the returned pointer in a variable, send it into printf and then to free(). Consider to rewrite your program in that way, that you allocate memory for the result in advance. If the input line cannot be longer than 256 chars the filtered output won't be larger.

Comment: @user5329483 I already resolved the issue with the help of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56796075/11110290 answer, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are using malloc which allocates memory from the heap and since you are calling this function again and again you are running out of memory.
To solve this issue you have to call the free() function on the pointer returned by your preprocessString function
In your main block

```
char *result=preprocessString(inputstring);
//Do whatever you want to do with this result
free(result);
```

Comment: You are my hero... I called the function from a printf, so i sort of assumed that it would be freed by default...

Comment: @b3nj4m1n C doesn't do any automatic garbage collection.

Comment: But unless your file is many megabytes, you're not likely to run out of memory.

Comment: This answer isn't complete, you still need to fix all the other problems I noted in my answer.

Comment: @Barmar This question was (At least primarily) about the segmentation fault, 3 of our answer 'only' improves the performace, and 1 of your answer doesn't seem to have any impact on the programm.

Comment: 1 can definitely cause segmentation faults, because you write outside the array boundaries. 2 might cause a segmentation fault because you read outside the array when printing; even if it doesn't, it causes garbage to be printed after the line. 3 is only a performance fix, that's true.

Comment: You could eliminate all these needless calls to `malloc` and `free` by allocating two line buffers in `main` and passing both of them to `preprocessString`. Where possible, it's generally good to avoid allocating something in one place and having to free it someplace else. Much better to have the allocation and free take place in the same scope where possible. It's annoying that anyone who calls your function has to know that it allocates memory that they have to free.

Comment: Freeing the allocated memory may seem to fix the problem, but the program still has undefined behavior except for files with very short strings: the amount of memory allocated is incorrect, it should be `char *result = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);`

Comment: @b3nj4m1n: this answer is incomplete. The code still has undefined behavior in multiple ways.

Answer (score 6):

You have several problems.

1. You're not allocating enough space. `sizeof(str)` is the size of a pointer, not the length of the string. You need to use

```
char *result = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
```

`+ 1` is for the terminating null byte.

2. You didn't add a terminating null byte to the result string. Add

```
result[j] = '\0';
```

before `return result;`

3. Once you find that the character matches an allowed character, there's no need to keep looping through the rest of the allowed characters. Add `break` after `j++`.
4. Your `main()` function is never freeing the results of `preprocessString()`, so you might be running out of memory.

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    char *processed = preproccessString(line);
    printf("%s\n", processed); 
    free(processed);
}
```

You could address most of these problems if you have the caller pass in the result string, instead of allocating it in the function. Just use two `char[256]` arrays in the `main()` function.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char const* const fileName = argv[1];
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char line[256], processed[256];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        processString(line, processed);
        printf("%s\n", processed); 
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Then just change the function so that the parameters are:

```
void preprocessString(const char *str, char *result)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be ```result[j] = '\0';```, but i tried j as well as i, I added 1 to the ```malloc()``` and i added the break, still a seg fault at the same position.

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: Post the full program.

Comment: @b3nj4m1n: As the corrections given in this answer doesn't help, please show us the calling code. Do you free the result anywhere?

Comment: There's also the whole not freeing allocated memory thing, though it doesn't look like the example program leaks enough to run out of heap after only 4000 lines.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I added that to my answer 5 minutes ago

Comment: @Barmar: you might change the prototype to `void preprocessString(const char *str, char *result);`

Comment: OT: regarding: `FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");`  when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "my error message" );`  to output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred

Comment: OT: Note: using `fgets()` will result in each read line ending with a '\n' (newline).   That newline will not be copied to the processed array.

Comment: @user3629249 That's OK, since he's printing a newline after the processed array.

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb is to make sure there is one free for every malloc/calloc call.

Also, a good tool to keep note of for the future is Valgrind. It's very good at catching these kinds of errors.

Answer (score 1):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for errors
4. properly checks for length of input string parameter
5. makes use of characteristic of `strchr()` also checking the terminating NUL byte
6. limits scope of visibility of local variables
7. the calling function is expected to properly cleaning up by passing the returned value to `free()`
8. the calling function is expected to check the returned value for NULL
9. informs compiler the user knows and accepts when an implicit conversion is made.
10. moves `allowedCharsArray` to 'file static scope' so does not have to be re-initialized on each pass through the loop and marks as 'const' to help the compiler catch errors

and now the proposed code: (note: edited per comments)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char *preproccessString(char *str) 
{
    // Create a new string of the size of the input string, so this might be bigger than needed but should never be too small
    char *result = calloc( sizeof( char ),  strlen(str)+1);
    if( !result )
    {
        perror( "calloc failed" );
        return NULL;
    }

    // Array of allowed chars 
    static const char *allowedCharsArray = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    // Loop over the input string
    for( int  j=0, i=0; str[i]; i++) 
    {
        if( strchr( allowedCharsArray, (char)toupper( str[i] ) ) )
        {
            // Set char at index j of result string to uppercase version of char currently under consideration
            result[j] = (char)toupper(str[i]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What do you think about preproccessString(**const** char*)?

Comment: The posted code does not *cleanly* compile: `result[j] = '\0';` refers to `j` that is defined only within the `for` statement. I make this mistake all the time, and I wish the scope of these variables was different, but the standard is what it is.

Comment: `toupper(str[i])` should be `toupper((unsigned char)str[i]) `to have fully defined behavior on architectures with `char` signed by default.

Comment: I agree, the scope of 'j' needs to be expanded.  I had added the appending of the NUL terminator byte as an after thought.   What I really should have done is replaced `malloc()` with `calloc()`.  I've edited the answer accordingly

Comment: the function: `toupper()` expects an `int` for a parameter, so `str[i]` will be properly promoted  However, casting it to `unsigned char` is useless and does not match the syntax of the function: `toupper()`

Comment: Last I checked, declaring variables inside a for loop like that is not allowed in C. All three parts need to be expressions, and int j=0 is not an expression.

Comment: @prushik,  Actually, `int j=0` is an expression.  Also in 'old' versions of C, declaring a variable in the first parameter to `for()` was not allowed.  However for any version of `c` after about '89, it is allowed (and encouraged).  Suggest also reading about the comma ',' operator

Comment: @user3629249 "j = 0" is an expression, but "int j = 0" is not, it is a statement, it does not evaluate to a value. something like "i = int j;" would not be legal. Even C++, which allows declarations within for loops like that, does not define them as an expression, but instead explicitly allows that type of declaration in for loop grammar rules. If newer versions of C allow this, it would be done the same way. Also, what does the comma operator have to do with this situation?

Comment: @user3629249 according to some research, its allowed in c99 and c11. Neither of which are fully supported by common c compilers (gcc, clang, msvcc, tcc),  although gcc allows this by default as an extension. I would avoid using such a feature for portability and personal preference. Unsure who would be "encouraging" its use.

Answer (score 1):

There are some major issues in your code:

- the amount of memory allocated is incorrect, `sizeof(str)` is the number of bytes in a *pointer*, not the length of the string it points to, which would also be incorrect. You should write `char *result = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);`
- the memory allocated in `preproccessString` is never freed, causing memory leaks and potentially for the program to run out of memory on **very** large files.
- you do not set a null terminator at the end of the `result` string

Lesser issues:

- you do not check if filename was passed nor if `fopen()` succeeded.
- there is a typo in `preproccessString`, it should be `preprocessString`
- you could avoid memory allocation by passing a properly sized destination array.
- you could use `isalpha` instead of testing every letter
- you should cast the `char` values as `unsigned char` when passing them to `toupper` because `char` may be a signed type and `toupper` is undefined for negative values except `EOF`.
- there are too many comments in your source file, most of which are obvious but make the code less readable.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// transform the string in `str` into buffer dest, keeping only letters and uppercasing them.
char *preprocessString(char *dest, const char *str) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)str[i])
            dest[j++] = toupper((unsigned char)str[i]);
    }
    dest[j] = '\0';
    return dest;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char line[256];
    char dest[256];
    char *filename;
    FILE *file;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing filename argument\n");
        return 1;
    }
    filename = argv[1];
    if ((file = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        printf("%s\n", preprocessString(dest, line)); 
    }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```